# JavaScript - how to select elements from node list

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

Here is my HTML:

```
<button class="btn" data-key="123456789">Show</button>
<button class="btn" data-key="abcdefghi">Show</button>
```

I also have iframes that have matching data-key attributes (i.e., for each button with a key there will be a corresponding iframe with the same key).

I need to grab the iframe with given key when the button with the corresponding key is clicked.

First I grab all the items with the given key:

```
var keyElems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-key="' + key + '"]');
```

This will return a nodelist with an iframe and button. Within `keyElems` I want to be able to just get the iframe element. Why can't I just do something like this?

```
var frame = keys.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
```

This doesn't seem to work, I'm assuming because keys is a nodelist. Is there a more elegant way to do this than just doing a loop and checking to see if the element is an iframe or not?

Comment: This usually indicates a deeper design problem. Consider using arrays or objects for representing your application data, what you're doing is effectively querying the presentation layer of your application in order to get its state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd just have to modify your selector to pick `iframe`

```
var keyElems = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[data-key="' + key + '"]');
```

If you're only expecting one iframe to be returned, use `querySelector` instead. It returns the first element from a `NodeList`

Comment: Perfect, that was the missing piece of syntax I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist, not a single HTML element, so it has no method `querySelectorAll`. In other words, you can't chain `querySelectorAll` method calls.

But then you've no need to; just modify your selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe[data-key="'+key+'"]');
```

For more complex purposes, where more computation is needed and merely extending the selector is not an option, you can harness `array.prototype.filter`

```
[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-key="'+key+'"]'), function(el) {
    return el.tagName == 'iframe';
});
```

Comment: why posting the same answer 3 min after ?

Comment: Is it inconceivable to you that I started writing it before seeing RUJordan's answer? He has rightly got the initial upvotes. I have tried to differentiate my answer by adding further info.